# How to find Sentence Transformer support languages?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, word-embedding, sentence-similarity, sentence-transformers

I want to get the sentence embedding results to find the sentence similarities in my NLP project. Since I am working with a low-resource language (Sinhala), I want to know whether any sentence_transformer [model](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html) supports my low-resource language. However, I was unable to find the pre-trained languages of those models. So How can I find that?
If those models are not trained with this language, How can I implement a sentence embedding model?